# setOnFocusChangeListener вызывается для всех EditText при изменении фокуса одного

Tags: android, kotlin

Я добавил две view с EditText в RecyclerView.

В onBindViewHolder:

```
row.inputField.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
    // print object identifier
}
```

Но когда я нажимаю на второй EditText, setOnFocusChangeListener вызывается дважды, для первого и второго EditText с **b=true**.

Почему setOnFocusChangeListener так работает?
Проблема воспроизводится на Android >5.

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык, пожалуйста

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov перевел

Comment: Потому что фокус для EditText;s так работает

Comment: @Style-7 а как работает? Мне нужно определить на каком EditText фокус чтобы изменить UI. В Listview такой проблемы нет и в 5 версии андроида тоже